# Give an infinite collection of intervals such that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ and $\cap^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n = \varnothing$

Tags: proof-writing

> Give an example of an infinite collection $A_n $ of intervals such that $A_{n+1} \subset A_n$ and $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n = \varnothing$.

I have come to the following collection of intervals, but dont know if it is correct nor how to prove it. $A_n = \left(0, \frac{1}{n^2}\right)$. How do I prove my example works?

EDIT: The intervals are on the real line!

Comment: Let $x\in \mathop{\cap}_{n =1}^{+\infty}A_n$. Then $0<x$ and $\forall n\in \Bbb N\left(x<\dfrac 1{n^2}\right)$. Conclude.

Comment: You can get $\varnothing$ with `\varnothing`.

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, the intervals are on the real line. My mistake!

Comment: @user1090614 That's how interpreted the question.

Comment: Suppose $x\in\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}$ and then we can prove it by using the squeeze theorem. The lim$\frac{1}{n^2}=0$ and lim$0=0$ Which forces the lim $x=0$. But $0\not \in\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}$. Thus we conclude...

Answer (score 1):

if $x \leq 0$, $x$ belongs to none of the sets.  If $x>0$, take $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ with $x > 1/n^2$.  Then $x$ does not belong to $\mathcal{A}_n$, so $x$ does not belong to the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The set containing sequences of $\frac{1}{n}$ approaching 1 as its limit (BUT IT DOESN'T CONTAIN $1$) from the LHS and the RHS. The answer to the sequence contained in your metric space is below.

> $$S = \{1 - \frac{1}{n}\} \bigcup \{1 + \frac{1}{n}\} : n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Generally, just unite two open sets, and don't include their limit point (This could make it closed and have a nonempty intersection).

If you know about separability, just make sure the intersection contains none of the sets closures!

Answer (score 0):

a(n)=[n,+∞)

so An+1⊂An

n=1⋂∞  An=∅